# Non-rechargeable Battery Gauge circuit / Coulomb counter

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry, monitor

I'm trying to find a cheap implementation/circuit to monitor the remaining capacity of a non-rechargeable battery to be specific Lithium thionyl chloride LiSOCI2 batteries. I am aware of TI and Maxim's solutions but i feel they are expensive, i found several coulomb counter projects but AFAIK they fully discharge the batteries to finish the test which for LI-ion (rechargeable) this is not a problem. I was thinking if it was possible to do with simple components (Transistors/Mosfets) and software using a microcontroller to do ? I would really appreciate if someone would point to the right direction. For the curious out there, it's going to be inlcuded in an energy/electricity meter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you want to measure? I mean, your words like charge/capacity/life are pretty general. If the voltage is enough, you can always make a supersimple circuit of 2 mosfets and feed that into MCU ADC and get the voltage.

Comment: @Ilya My apologies for the vague question. I would like to know the remaining capacity of the battery. AFAIK they would need a load for the voltage to be measured, but for specifics of what to do i'm still in the dark.

Comment: The best way to know it is to have the discharge curve of the battery saved somewhere (after all, it's hardware characteristic). So you measure voltage and look it up where on discharge curve it is

Comment: So if i were to put a known load resistor which gets switched with a mosfet and a shunt resistor i am able to measure voltage under load within a brief time and current and compare with the discharge curve which i presume is in the datasheet of the battery , correct ?

Comment: A shunt? That's a massive overkill. You open mosfet to some high value resistor to gnd and feed the high side of resistor into mcu's adc and get voltage straight out of that. And that will let you estimate the charge. At least in 10% quantities it should work ok (0%, 10%, 20%...)

Comment: That sounds very simple, I'm going to try it . Thank you very much for sharing your insights and thoughts with me.

Comment: I checked the discharge curves of the battery and sadly it is not very useful since the voltage is pretty flat in most of the life cycle then at the end a steep drop, am i missing something ? https://www.lithium-bt.com/images/sheets/HCB-ER14250.pdf

Comment: that's exactly what's good about batteries: they keep voltage for the most part of the charge. But I'll be honest, I've never seen a curve which is...not even a curve for the most part. But I have an idea. If you look at higher current discharge curve (36ma), it's sloped. You can connect higher current load very short, measure voltage, see its status and close that load. But make sure you know the entire current drawn from battery during measurement. You can make measurement so quick it won't even make much difference. Well, depending on your application. Gotta get a little creative

Comment: Thanks again. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: I think a coulomb counter would be the right way to go here, not measuring the voltage. Or if you know how much current your circuit uses, you could even just measure the time it's been on. But how would you know that the user didn't insert a half-empty battery?

Comment: Why don't you use something like LTC4150?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, measure the current periodically with an IC like INA219 and integrate it over time to know the battery consumed.

Using a shunt resistor based current monitor like INA219 you can get about 1kHz of load current sampling rate. Only situations where this approach might be less accurate is if you have many magnitudes of dynamic range of current to measure (A to uA) or if you have short bursts (few us) of high current consumed you.

[image: INA219 current/power monitor]

If you're measuring every ms, then keep accumulating the current up measured in A in variable, say `charge_count`. You can now check `charge_count` against the battery capacity to see how much capacity is left.

To calculate the battery capacity, let's take an example of a 1 Ah battery, which means you can draw 1A for an hour. So it means 1A for 3600000 ms. So you can check `charge_count` against 3600000 value to see how much battery is left.

Measuring the current in A requires you to convert the sampled value to float, you can change the entire calculations to use integers if you use appropriate scaling.